# Generate random array of integers with a number of appearance of each integer

Tags: python, random

I need to create a random array of 6 integers between 1 and 5 in Python but I also have another data say a=[2 2 3 1 2] which can be considered as the capacity. It means 1 can occur no more than 2 times or 3 can occur no more than 3 times.

I need to set up a counter for each integer from 1 to 5 to make sure each integer is not generated by the random function more than a[i].

Here is the initial array I created in python but I need to find out how I can make sure about the condition I described above. For example, I don't need a solution like [2 1 5 4 5 4] where 4 is shown twice or [2 2 2 2 1 2].

```
solution = np.array([np.random.randint(1,6) for i in range(6)])
```

Even if I can add probability, that should work. Any help is appreciated on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an pool of data that have the most counts and then pick from there:

```
import numpy as np

a = [2, 2, 3, 1, 2]

data = [i + 1 for i, e in enumerate(a) for _ in range(e)]
print(data)
result = np.random.choice(data, 6, replace=False)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5]
[1 3 2 2 3 1]
```

Note that data is array that has for each element the specified count, then we pick randomly from data this way we ensure that you won't have more elements that the specify count.

**UPDATE**

If you need that each number appears at least one time, you can start with a list of each of the numbers, sample from the rest and then shuffle:

```
import numpy as np

result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a = [1, 1, 2, 0, 1]
data = [i + 1 for i, e in enumerate(a) for _ in range(e)]
print(data)
result = result + np.random.choice(data, 1, replace=False).tolist()
np.random.shuffle(result)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 5]
[3, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2]
```

Notice that I subtract 1 from each of the original values of `a`, also the original `6` was change to `1` because you already have 5 numbers in the variable `result`.

Comment: You need `replace=False` in that `np.random.choice` call; without it, there's still the possibility of selecting an element multiple times and so exceeding the counts.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you also help me add another condition to it saying that all the numbers must be generated at least once?

Answer (score 0):

You could test your count against a dictionary

```
import random

a = [2, 2, 3, 1, 2]
d = {idx: item for idx,item in enumerate(a, start = 1)}
l = []
while len(set(l) ^ set([*range(1, 6)])) > 0:
    l = []
    while len(l) != 6:
        x = random.randint(1,5)
        while l.count(x) == d[x]:
            x = random.randint(1,5)
        l.append(x)

print(l)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you also help me add another condition to it saying that all the numbers must be generated at least once? For example if a is changed to the list below, I don't want l to be [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2].

Comment: @Sarah yes this should be possible I will take a look shortly!

Comment: @Sarah Check it out! :)